# Autofill time when I click a text field with adobe

Tags: time, autofill

How can I set a page to autofill the time when I click on the text field?

I am trying to create a sign in/out form and need to input the times of in and out!

Thanks in advance

I am not sure exactly where to start. I am not a programmer (no surprise) but I have learned to understand the code I need and have pieced the form together one feature at a time